# How to call instance method based on selected option?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I made this code but I don't know how to finish it. I have object `ContactDetail`. Also I have one prototype method `doSomething`. 
Each `ContactDetail` instance has property `optionEl` which is html option element. I made few instances and appended its options to select. Now if I choose value from select, I want to call `doSomething` method based on my choice. 
**I would like to do some solution without html changes (no id declarations) and also I will appreciate solution with pure javascript (no jquery data).** 
I would code this on my own, but Im out of ideas right now. So Im asking you for help.

**EDIT1:**
I totaly forgot to say, sometimes options are detached or appended to select again, so then indexes doesn't work.

**EDIT2:**
I had to modify my example, so you can understand it better.

Here is jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/kkha3/

```
var selectDetail = $("<select />");

var ContactDetail = function(name) {
    this.name = name;    
    this.optionEl = $("<option/>").text(this.name); 
    // there are like 5 more properties
}

ContactDetail.prototype.doSomething = function() {
    console.log(this.name); // this is just a debug, that proves in example
                            // that correct instance was called, but there is no
                            // such a thing in fact
    // here I call some more things based choice
    // for example if you select contact detail address, 
    // then it puts into form more inputs (like ZIP, state, street..
}

var contactDetailList = [];
contactDetailList.push(new ContactDetail("a"));
contactDetailList.push(new ContactDetail("b"));
contactDetailList.push(new ContactDetail("c"));
contactDetailList.push(new ContactDetail("d"));
contactDetailList.push(new ContactDetail("e"));
contactDetailList.push(new ContactDetail("f"));


for (var i = 0; i < contactDetailList.length; i++) {
    contactDetailList[i].optionEl.appendTo(selectDetail);
}

selectDetail.change(function(event) {
   // how to call doSomething() on instance that is selected??
});

selectDetail.appendTo("body");
```

Comment: Just a suggestion don't use `select` as a variable name. Reference http://www.javascripter.net/faq/reserved.htm

Comment: @Satpal thx you are right. In fact my own code is much more longer and names are completly different. This is just short example. But examples should be correct too ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe you could do something with jQuery's data() functionality. I would slightly modify your `ContactDetail` "class" so that it attaches itself to your option element:

```
var ContactDetail = function(name) {
    this.name = name;    
    this.optionEl = $("<option/>").text(this.name);
    // attach this ContactDetail to the option
    this.optionEl.data('contact-detail', this);
}
```

And then later in your change handler, you can get the selected option element, and retrieve the instance of the `ContactDetail` class from it:

```
select.change(function(event) {
   var contactDetail = $('option:selected', this).data('contact-detail');
   if (contactDetail)
       contactDetail.doSomething();
});
```

This gives you total freedom from that global array you used to build your list.

[jsFiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/kkha3/11/)

Comment: Although I did not want to use jQuery data, but it is probably the best solution.

Answer (score 1):

You could do this:

```
select.change(function(event) {
   var selectedIndex = this.selectedIndex;
   contactDetailList[selectedIndex].doSomething();
});
```

JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/kkha3/12/

Comment: I like your solution. But I totaly forgot to say one thing. Somethimes options are detached and appended again to the select. So then, indexes doesnt work. But I will think about if it can be done somehow.

Comment: @Windkiller: My solution works without indices (Meta, sorry to hijack your answer).

Comment: @Cory no worries ^^ Yours is the best one :D

Answer (score 0):

I added a click event on the option, maybe this will help you:

```
var selectDetail = $("<select />");
var ContactDetail = function(name) {
    var _this = this;
    _this.name = name;    
    _this.optionEl = $("<option/>").text(this.name);
    _this.optionEl.click(function(){
        _this.doSomething(_this)
    });
}

ContactDetail.prototype.doSomething = function(obj) {
    console.log(obj.name); 
}
```

here the [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/LvNJn/)

Comment: Not a bad idea. But the solution doesn't work in every browser. I think that different event (not click) needs to be there.

Comment: In google chrome and chromium... 
Selecting option is probably not considered as a click on it.